# How do I select a panel from the jnplot from the probe_interactions() function in interactions() in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I would like to select one panel from the jnplot generated by probe_interactions() for a three-way interactions. The get_panel() command from cowplot does not seem to work here. Does anybody know whther this is possible? I may be overlooking something, I am not terribly familiar with cowplot.

Here's an illustration of what I want to do:

1. I ran the probe_interactions() command from *interactions* for a three-way interaction with `jnplot=T`, like so `plot <- probe_interaction(fit, pred = pred, modx = mod1, mod2 = mod2, jnplot = T)`
2. I want to use the johnson_neyman plots this generates `plot <- plot$simslopes$jnplot`
3. Then I only want to have (and be able to edit) the plot for -1 *SD* on mod2, I have tried this `ggdraw(get_panel(plot, 1))`. But this just generates the same plot.

Does anybody know if this is possible at all? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a minimum reproducible  example and your expected result?

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not completely sure what extra information you are looking for. The above should work (or, rather, not work) when using any three continuous variables in the interaction and a continuous outcome variable.

You could just recreate the above by creating a dataset with four (random) variables and run these commands for *interactions* and *cowplot*. The jnplot I create in step 2 has three panels, one for -1 SD, the mean, and the other for +1 SD on mod2. I would like to be able to, as it were, "take" the former panel and edit it.

Comment: That’s the question.  I mean you should provide the specific code that we can run. Now that you have said we can recreate a dataset with four random variables, why don’t you provide the code ( include seed and how you plot).  This means reproducible.  Code is the best way to help us understand your problem but you don’t provide anything we can run directly.

Comment: Read about how to give a reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example